# start image animation by clicking on same image

Tags: android, android-animation

i have image animation(moves bottom to top and top to bottom),and it is loading automatically when ever i am install into device but i won't that,my requirement is i want click on that image then only animation has to start,
        please help me

ondraw method is:

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

```
    int z= c.getHeight()/2;
    Log.e("bharat","z is"+z);
    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        //x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = c.getHeight()/2;


    } else {
        //x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if (((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0))) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

    if(touching){ 
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE); 
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
    }




activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.example.AnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="imageClicked" />

</RelativeLayout>
**animatedview.java**

     //this is for image moving from bottom to top

     public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{

    static int count=0;
    private Context mContext;
    int x = 150;
    int y = 450;
    private float a,b;
    private int xVelocity = 10;
    private int yVelocity = 15;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 25;
    BitmapDrawable ball;
    boolean touching;
    boolean dm_touched = false;

    int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;

    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        mContext = context;  
        h = new Handler();
    } 

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate(); 
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
        if (x<0 && y <0) {
            //x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = c.getHeight()/2;


        } else {
            //x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;
            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
            }
            if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
            }
        }
        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         Log.d("bharat","ontouch called");
        int touchType = event.getAction();

         switch(touchType){


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                a = event.getX();
                b = event.getY();
                touching = true;
                if (dm_touched) {
                    x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                    y = (int) b - bm_offsety;
                }
                break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                 //x and y give you your touch coordinates
                  a = event.getX();
                  b = event.getY();
                  touching = true;
                  Log.d("bharat","action_down called");
                  if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) {

                        count++;
                       Log.i("bharat",""+count);
                       Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                       intent1.putExtra("score", count);

                    }

                    dm_touched = true;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                default:

                    dm_touched = false;
                    touching = false;


                }

                return true;
    }
    }

**MainActivity.java**

         //here i am want to get the image the view and by clicking on that image only animation should  loaded 

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
                View  animatedView =  findViewById(R.id.anim_view);
                      ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            }
```

Comment: Please post some sufficient code also where is your animation code ? Where is your code of `animatedview.java` file ?

Comment: thaks for ur reply,i am added animatedview.java file

Comment: Where you are using `animatedview.java` in your `MainActivity` ?

Comment: from main_activity.xml  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
<com.example.example.AnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="imageClicked" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Please post it in your question only.

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching any click listners in the AnimatedView. Modify your constructor as

```
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context;  
    h = new Handler();
    setOnTouchListener(this)
}
```

Also call `invalidate()` in the `onTouchEvent()`

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchType = event.getAction();

     switch(touchType){


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanku friend,but my doubt is,i want postpone the image animation until i am click on that image.how it is possible

Comment: in the `onDraw` function, the runnable is called no matter what. instead call it only when `touching = true`

Comment: i can't understand what is ur thought,wii u please explain clearly

Comment: ondraw will be called every time the view is created or modified. So if you need an animation happening only if u clicked, create a flag that becomes true when u click. Then based on this falg call the Runnable in the onDraw()

Comment: i am new for new for android,where i have to write a flag,will u please modify my code

Comment: protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
        ...
        if(touching){
            h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
    }

Comment: i am did same thing image is paused bottom of the screen but animation is not done when i click on that image.

Comment: i changed the answer, look up